# I would like to use the framework UIViewController as a superclass protocol of a project class

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

Using the collection view, I made a framework to flick and slide two cells side by side.

My goal is to use this framework's MainViewController as a superclass in the project class.

Add MainViewController to the project class subclass like super class protocol,
I want to inherit and use it as it is.

I made framework (library) with cocoa touch framework.

Direct drag and drop without using cocoapods etc. I have already imported into the project that I want to introduce this library.

This framework (library) has been added to embedded binaries and Linked frameworks and libraries.

I want to use a claim work like the following code.

```
//Project class (class to be treated as a subclass of framework MainViewController)


import UIKit
import SlidingCellWithDrag0Framework

// I want to use it like this.

class ViewController: MainViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
    }
}
```

But I can not build
An error has occurred.

ld: framework not found SlidingCellWithDrag0Framework
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Treat the library as a superclass,
I want to realize the library function (function to slide two collection view cells by flicking) in a project subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your framework in `general -> embedded binaries` like below:
Directly drag and drop in this location
[image]

Then build, your code will work

> This will work only those simulator in witch your framework build, So
>   first build your framework in any simulator and after that copy that
>   .framework from products and drag & drop in your project and build
>   with the same simulator. Otherwise, if you want your framework will
>   work on every device then you have to add run script and create the
>   build target for distribution

Comment: Both embedded binaries and linked frameworks and binaries have already been added with the + button.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I can build successfully your framework in my project so i think you are doing wrong while adding framework in your project

Comment: The version of xcode you are using is 10.1. The swift is 4.2.

Comment: >> Otherwise, if you want your framework will work on every device then you have to add run script and create the build target for distribution                         /// Does it mean that you can use framework with cocoapods etc?

Comment: Yes, you can distribute your framework and your framework will work with all devices and simulator

Comment: It seems that I solved it !
When I resolved, the types of simulators for the two projects were not common,
First of all, when building with the framework project of xcode, the error of the project to which framework was introduced was eliminated and built.
You can use the function of MainViewController.
Thank you Mr Jogendar.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me so kind and easy to understand.

Comment: @tnk: Your welcome, Please accept and upvote my answer